# Excel VBA User form entry to a specific range inside worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

So I am currently trying to have a user input some information and put that information in a specific range based on what values in the dropdown list are selected. For example, I selected Monday, so I want the information to go in the Range A1:A12, but if they select Tuesday then go to range G1:G12.

Also, if the range is already full with data, I'd like for it to tell the user that it is full. Do not have any example code, but here is a psuedo-code example

```
Private Sub cbSubmit_Click()
    range("A2").Select
    ActiveCell.End(xlDown).Select
    lastrow = ActiveCell.Row
    MsgBox lastrow
        If ComboBox1.Value = "Monday" Then
        Cells(lastrow + 1, 1).Value = tb1.Text
        Cells(lastrow + 1, 2).Value = tb2.Text
    End If
    If ComboBox1.Value = "Tuesday" Then
        range("G2").Select
        ActiveCell.End(xlDown).Select
        lastrow2 = ActiveCell.Row
        Cells(lastrow2 + 1, 1).Value = tb1.Text
        Cells(lastrow2 + 1, 2).Value = tb2.Text
    End If
End Sub
```

Also, in the above code, is there a better way to find the last cell in the range that is blank? This one only works if there is already data in the range and that's not always the case. 
And also check some sort of CountA or something to see if the range is already full of data. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the issue you are having?

Comment: Doing the check to see if the range of cells is already full pretty much.

Comment: `If Cells(X+1,Y+1) <> vbNullString Then` 'there is data in the cell. It could also be a space, so it might be worth using `Trim(Cells(X+1,Y+1))` but that's up to you I suppose - whether or not spaces = data or you would ever find that and what factors that depends on.

Comment: Right, so how can I check the entire range as opposed to just the cell?

Comment: `For Each c in Range("A1:A10") 

    If c <> vbNullString Then 

        'Found Data 

        Exit For

    End If

Next`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will answer just so I can demonstrate code better.

As I said in the comments, if you want to check each value in a range, you can do so like this:

```
Dim c
For Each c in Range("A1:A10") 'Whatever your range to check is
    If c <> vbNullString Then
        'Found Data - not empty
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

If you're just checking 2 cells as it looks like you are, you should probably just use:

```
If Cells(lastrow2 + 1, 1) <> vbNullString and Cells(lastrow2 + 1, 2) <> vbNullString
```

If you just want to add the data to the bottom of the list, your code is already getting the last row and adding to it ... so each time you call this:

```
ActiveCell.End(xlDown).Select
lastrow2 = ActiveCell.Row
```

It is getting the last row and the rest of your code adds it to the end.

One more thing. You should really replace this:

```
range("G2").Select
ActiveCell.End(xlDown).Select
lastrow2 = ActiveCell.Row
```

With this:

```
lastrow2 = range("G2").End(xlDown).Row
```

You should avoid using select as often as possible.

In my experience, it is really only necessary when displaying a different sheet.

Comment: Ok so if the cell has content, how do I make the code skip to the next line? I'm guessing something like `Cells (lastrow2 + 2, 1)?`

Comment: I edited for u - looks like you are already skipping to the next line with your code. .End(xlDown) will get the last cell with data. If you add to it, it should always be blank. Make sense?

Comment: Makes sense, now I'm guessing if I wanted to error out to the user when the range is full I could just start a count and check that in the if statement as well?

Comment: If you're just expanding the range vertically (with a limit), just check the last row and see if it is the max and then let the user know. `lastrow2 = ActiveCell.Row` You could use `If lastrow2 = maxValue Then ...` Also, see my final edit for one more thing I would recommend changing.